# how to change default color when switch is "on"(blue to green) in forms xamarin. In ios default it is GReen but in android it is blue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

wirth this code i am getting swith in blue color when it "on". i want to change it to green.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace swithcasedemo
{
    public class MyPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MyPage ()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout { 
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Hello ContentPage",
                        HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
                    },
                    new Switch{
                        HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,


                    },


                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me using Android >= 4.1

```
//need to reference Drawables otherwise StateListDrawable is not recognized.
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

//...
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       //...
       mySwitch = view.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.theSwitchIdFromXml);
       //... 

        Android.Graphics.Color colorOn = Android.Graphics.Color.Green;
        Android.Graphics.Color colorOff = Android.Graphics.Color.Brown;
        Android.Graphics.Color colorDisabled = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;

        StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked }, new ColorDrawable(colorOn));
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateEnabled }, new ColorDrawable(colorDisabled));
        drawable.AddState(new int[] { }, new ColorDrawable(colorOff));

        mySwitch.ThumbDrawable = drawable;
  }
```

The "default" state needs to be added as the last.

I Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi
I want to do that also but for API 15 ( 4.0.3 – 4.0.4).
You have an solution how to do that. Or it is not possible to this in API 15.

Comment: You can check if anything that is not included in the API you use, has an equivalent from Compat libraries.

Answer (score 1):

For your IOS project on Xamarin, you need just to put this line to FinishedLaunching method of AppDelegate.cs

```
            UISwitch.Appearance.OnTintColor = Color.FromHex("#yourColor").ToUIColor();
```